# Google sheets beginners course overall amounts of products in stock formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

im an absolute beginner, that has to do a test for a data analytics course.

I have to express in a formula: what is the overall amount of products in stock. everything on google sheets.

the link for the product list is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m67VmLZispyTwFTmPdppsdJNtbvnZsZK2LBCSchUWmU/edit?usp=sharing

My idea was to multiply the quantity per unit times the unit in stock. the problem i have is, that the quantity per unit column in E is also strings, so i dont know how to convert this column so that i can multiply it with the unit in stock column. also i am not sure if this formula is right in the first place.
would be glad, if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi! Since the qty to be extracted varies a lot in column E, you'd have to add a column and have these unit qty there, if you can't have the dataset extracted bring that info.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. what do you mean with qty and in which column would i have to try, if the formula is working?

Comment: i get a parse error if i type it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(E2:E; 
 "[a-zA-Z-\.]+"; ); " ")&""; "^$"; "1")*1; 
 "select Col1*Col2 label Col1*Col2''"))
```

[image]